# AWS: I deployed my microservice on AWS and it's working fine but the service class is unable to read data from the file

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ecr

I just deployed my first microservice. My microservice is working fine. All routes are working. But the service class inside the microservice is not working properly. The service class is not reading data from the CSV file.

Below is the code I am using to read data from CSV file.

```
public class ReadCsvUtil {

private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ReadCsvUtil.class);

public List<String[]> readData() throws IOException { 
    
    String file = ".\\src\\main\\resources\\pensioners.csv";
    List<String[]> content = new ArrayList<>();
    try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
        String line = "";
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            content.add(line.split(","));
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        LOGGER.debug(e.getMessage());
    }
    
    return content;
}
```

}

The service class invokes the above function to get details of all the people.

The above code is working fine on my desktop and I am able to get details but code is not working on AWS. Also, I tried to remove the CSV and manually enter the values and it's working in AWS. So I am 99% sure there is some problem in reading the CSV files.

Is there anyway I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the path to the file one directory up, instead of

```
String file = ".\\src\\main\\resources\\pensioners.csv";
```

try,

```
String file = "..\src\main\resources\pensioners.csv";
```

I presume the AWS sever is ubuntu and your local is windows OS.